# can someone enplane to me this method how it works : inverted half pyramid pattern

Tags: algorithm

Given Pattern :

```
G H I J
D E F
B C
A
```

**i wnat to know why i used this method and why i writ it like this i want to know ever thing form start
this is the code that i used.i want explan to everything so i understand it clearly
also i weill be grateful if u give me an easy code give the same ouput other than this one :) Thank You**

```
    public class Main
    {            
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int alphabet = 71;
                    for (int i = 3; i>= 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    System.out.print((char) alphabet + " ");
                    alphabet++;
                    x=j;
                }
                alphabet=alphabet-(x+1+i);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with design patterns. Use algorithm instead.

Comment: There may be no-one better suited to answer the question of why you wrote the code that way than yourself.

Comment: I didn't wrote it by my self BTW

Answer (score 0):

Characters in Java can be converted to integer. You can find more about it by searching ''character integer values java'' from Google.

Here is example which demonstrates characters integer values and other version of your code.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] alphabets = new char[] {
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'
        };
        int A = 65; // Integer value of character 'A'

        // Print characters as integers
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print((int) alphabets[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Print integers as characters
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabets.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print((char) (A + i) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        // Array index of first character (G) is 6
        int first = 6;
        for (int width = 4; width > 0; --width) { // Four rows

            // Print characters of current row
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                char current = alphabets[first + x];
                System.out.print(current + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
            // Calculate first character of next row
            first -= width - 1;
        }
    }

}
```